# Actualizar cantidad de un producto existente en carrito de compras

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

El problema que tengo es que no se de que forma pueda hacer incrementar la cantidad del producto existente, y si no existe se agregre al carrito de compras, soy nuevo en el desarrollo, espero puedan ayudarme.
aqui dejo mi método usado para el carrito.

```
public function additem ( Request $request )
{
    $producto_new = $request->except(['btnAccion','_token']);        
    $producto_id = $producto_new['id'];         
    $carrito = session('carrito', [] );
   
    $mensaje= "";
    if (is_numeric($producto_new['id'])) {
        $id = $producto_new['id'];
    }
    if (is_string($producto_new['name'])) {
        $name = $producto_new['name'];
    }
    if (is_numeric($producto_new['cantidad'])) {
        $cantidad = $producto_new['cantidad'];
    }
    if (is_numeric($producto_new['precio'])) {
        $precio = $producto_new['precio'];
    }
    if (!isset( $carrito ))
    {
        $producto = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'cantidad' => $cantidad,
            'precio' => $precio
        );    
        $carrito[0] = $producto;              
    }
    else 
    {
        $idProducts = array_column( $carrito ,'id');
        if (in_array($id,  $idProducts)) {
            echo '';
        }
        else
        {
            $carrito [] = $producto_new; 
            foreach ($carrito as $indice => $producto) {
                $currentproductid = $producto_id;
                if ( $currentproductid == $producto_id ) {
                    $carrito[$indice]['cantidad'] = $producto_new['cantidad'];
                }
            }  
        }
    } 
    session(['carrito' => $carrito ]);
    return redirect('sales')->with('mensaje', $mensaje);
}
```

Este es mi formulario donde capturo mis productos de la base de datos una vez recopilados aqui mediante el boton Add los proceso al carrito de compras

```
<form action="{{ Route('sales.additem') }}" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $product->name }}">
<input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" class="form-control input-lg " min="1" value="<?php echo 1 ?>">  
<input type="hidden" name="precio" id="precio" value="{{$product->sale_price}}">
<!-- Button for add product in cart -->
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="btnAccion" value="Agregar" type="submit" >
Add
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes al agregar `var_dump($producto_new);` en la función _additem_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de usar solo índice numérico para cada producto en el carrito, asigna id, por ejemplo:

```
$carrito = [
    id_producto_1 => [
        'id' => id_producto_1,
        'nombre' => 'Nombre de producto 1',
        'cantidad' => 1,
        'precio' => 10
    ],
    id_producto_2 => [
        'id' => id_producto_2,
        'nombre' => 'Nombre de producto 2',
        'cantidad' => 1,
        'precio' => 15
    ],
];
```

Supongo que en alguna parte de tu proyecto accedes a ID desde `$carrito[$indice]['id']` y por eso lo dejé, así no tienes que modificar el resto de código.

Con esto podrás acceder a cada producto con `$carrito[$id_de_producto]` y, comenzando en `additem()`, te sirve para saber si ya existe el producto en el carrito o no:

```
public function additem ( Request $request )
{
    $carrito = session('carrito', [] );
    $producto_new = $request->except(['btnAccion','_token']);        
   
    $mensaje= "";
    // Crear y validar variables con asignación ternaria
    $id = (is_numeric($producto_new['id'])) ? $producto_new['id'] : 0;
    $nombre = (is_numeric($producto_new['nombre'])) ? $producto_new['nombre'] : '';
    $cantidad = (is_numeric($producto_new['cantidad'])) ? $producto_new['cantidad'] : 0;
    $precio = (is_numeric($producto_new['precio'])) ? $producto_new['precio'] : 0;

    // Validar que los datos son correctos
    if($id > 0 && !empty($nombre) && $cantidad > 0)
    {
        // El producto no está en carrito, hay que agregarlo
        if (!isset( $carrito[$id] ))
        {
            $producto = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $name,
                'cantidad' => $cantidad,
                'precio' => $precio
            );    
            $carrito[$id] = $producto;              
        }
        else 
        {
            // El producto ya está en carrito, incrementar cantidad
            $carrito[$id]['cantidad'] += $cantidad;
        }
        // Actualizar variable de sesión
        session(['carrito' => $carrito ]);
    }
    return redirect('sales')->with('mensaje', $mensaje);
}
```

Comment: de ante mano, muchas gracias por el apoyo, acabo de probar tu respuesta, pero sigo sin tener exito ya que no procese alguna accion al presiona el boton agregar

Comment: @MANUEL, edita la pregunta para agregar el código del formulario donde tienes ese botón y cómo lo procesas.

Comment: Por cierto, si ya tienes un carrito en sesión, primero debes vaciarlo, porque el formato es diferente a lo que estabas manejando.

Comment: ok,..
si elimine el contenido del carrito antes de probar